# Scala app to transpose columns into rows

Tags: beginner, scala, apache-spark

This is the first application or really any Scala I have every written. So far it functions as I would hope it would. I just found this community and would love some peer review of possible improvements or just tell me flat out what I'm doing wrong.

This code is supposed to read a table of tables then take all of the values from that table transpose the columns into rows and write them all to a master table with three additional columns. So far it does everything except the looping which I just haven't gotten to yet. This question is not about how to do the looping and really only hoping to critique what I have here so far. I did change some variable names and a few things I had to mask.

```
//how to call
//spark-submit --verbose --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --class App scala-maven-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ SQLContext, SparkSession }
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.util.Calendar

//this will call createStuff function for each table_name value in table
//TODO: Add loop and call CreateStuff with values from list returned from stuff_to_run
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //do I have to create the SparkSession value twice or can I pass this into the function?
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("App").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    val stuff_to_run = spark.sql("select table_name from schema.table").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList
    println(stuff_to_run)
    CreateStuff("stuff");
  }

  def CreateStuff(stuffName: String): Unit = {
    var tablename = stuffName
    var column_stack = ""
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("App").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    //is there a better way to get year and month
    val Year = Calendar.getInstance.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val Month = Calendar.getInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
    val twodigitmonth = "%02d".format(Month)
    val yrmnth = Year.toString + twodigitmonth.toString
    //get all of the data from the base table
    val raw_table = spark.sql("select *, '" + tablename + "' as stuffname, '" + yrmnth + "' as yrmnth from schema." + tablename)
    //transpose all columns into rows
    val string_table = raw_table.select(raw_table.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)): _*)
    //get column besides 3 defined these are the only ones which are not dynamic
    val selectColumns2 = string_table.columns.toSeq.filter(x => (x != "val1" && x != "stuffname" && x != "yrmnth"))
    val columnCount = selectColumns2.size
    //comma and quote
    selectColumns2.foreach { e =>
      column_stack += "'" + e + "', " + e + ", "
    }

    val collist = column_stack.mkString("").dropRight(1)
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    val unPivotDF = string_table.select($"val1", $"stuffname", $"yrmnth",
      expr("stack(" + selectColumns2.size + ", " + collist.dropRight(1) + ") as (fieldname, fieldvalue)"))
    //unPivotDF.show()
    //insert records into combined table
    unPivotDF.createOrReplaceTempView("stuff_temp")
    spark.sql("insert into schema.combined_stuff select * from stuff_temp")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Immediately I'd ask if there's any specific style guide that allows
these vastly different names, otherwise I'd suggest following IDE hints
and/or a linter and rename the variables and methods to be more
consistent (e.g. `[cC]amelCase` for everything).

Also, "stuff" is not a great name for anything ... what stuff are we
talking about?  In fact the first line of `CreateStuff` already shows
that there's a better name, `tableName` for the parameter, probably
`createTable` for the method.  `yrmnth` is especially bad too, three
vowels saved from `yearMonth` and in the process made the name
unreadable for the casual observer.

Seems like the spark session is created twice and the comment even says
so - I'd suggest passing the variable into the method, that's fairly
straightforward by either passing it as a parameter, or extending `App`
with a member variable.

The SQL queries are created by concatenating strings and there's usually
better ways, here probably a query builder.

`columnCount` is unused, `selectColumns2` has `2` as the suffix, even
though there's no `1`, that can just be `selectColumns`.

The loop for `columnStack` could be in its own method so it's a little
small section that could be tested on its own too, returning what is now
`collist`, `formatColumnsList(columns: Seq[String]): String` perhaps.
Again, if a query builder could do all this it would be a bit cleaner
than concatenating strings.

The construction for `yrmnth` is pretty convoluted for what it does, I'd
suggest finding a more succinct approach, e.g.

```
val yearMonth = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM").format(LocalDateTime.now())
```

That would require a recent Java for `java.time.LocalDateTime` and
`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.  But even without there should be
better ways.  If everything fails the whole section should at least be
in its own method, e.g. `formatDate(calendar Calendar): String`.

The bottom part of `unPivotDF` uses a temporary table - is that the best
way to go, or could the data be inserted directly?

Answer (score 0):

`tablename` doesn't need to be a `var`, it's never mutated, and it appears to be totally unneeded. Use the method's passed parameter directly.

`column_stack` is also unneeded. You can go directly from `selectColumns2` to `collist` without an intermediate variable or `dropRight()` adjustments.

```
val collist = selectColumns2.flatMap(e => Seq(s"'$e'",e)).mkString(", ")
```